Switching titlegraphics and date in RMarkdown's beamer presentation
Consider the following YAML header
title: "Project name"
author: "**Author1**, Author2"      
date: "Conference, 2024"
output: 
  beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{logo.png}}

Using the previous I obtain the following

.
How can I invert the date and titlegraphic in the slide? What I would like to have is the logo below the authors and then "Conference, 2024" at the bottom of the slide.

If your beamer version is up-to-date (version v3.70 or newer), you could do:
---
title: "Project name"
author: "**Author1**, Author2"      
date: "Conference, 2024"
output: 
  beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{example-image-duck}}
  - |
    \setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
      \vbox{}
      \vfill
      \begingroup
        \centering
        \usebeamertemplate{title}
        \vskip1em\par
        \usebeamertemplate{author}
        \usebeamertemplate{institute}
        \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
        \vskip0.5em
        \usebeamertemplate{date}
      \endgroup
      \vfill
    }
---

test


